# Eliminate bandwidth bottlenecks between far-away computers

Tags: internet, bandwidth

Our office location (in Karlsruhe, Germany) has fiber-optic internet access with 500MBit/s upload and download speed. This speed is confirmed by e.g. https://www.speedtest.net/ (reaching > 400MBit/s in both directions).

A colleague of mine located in Tokyo, Japan has a fast internet connection as well, his speedtest.net results show nearly 1GBit/s in both directions.

We have installed a speed test tool on one of our servers (inside the office LAN). If I run this from my home location (~20km from the office away), I get roughly the speed of my own internet connection (50MBit/s). If my colleague in Tokyo runs this speedtest, he gets different results depending on the time of the day, sometimes 50MBit/s (which is ok) but sometimes as low as 0.4MBit/s (which keeps him from remote working completely).

It seems to me like the bottleneck is neither on our end nor on his end, but in the connection in between. Is this assumption reasonable? Is there anything we can do to get a faster connection between this far points?

Comment: When you use speedtest.net, do you remember which server it chooses to test against? For example, from Tokyo, is it always against the "local" ISP, or against some other ISP in the area, or even somewhere more distant? It's not a universal "from here to ~the internet~" test; it's a test to specific test servers hosted by specific ISPs in specific locations (which you can choose as well – e.g. from Tokyo, you can try to use the test server hosted by your German ISP).